# UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewLayout validateLayoutInRect accertion

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm creating app with collection view with custom collection view layout. All works fine until one cell removed. After [collectionView reloadData] all seems good. But after collection view scrolls application crashes with assertion.

```
Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000060016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 12}
```

I already dug into many answers on stackOverflow, trying many things but still can't get rid of this problem.

Small example project with my custom layout and this problem I uploaded here:

[https://github.com/fizzy871/CollectionViewCustomLayoutBugFix](https://github.com/fizzy871/collViewBugTest)

There is collection view and "remove cell" button which removes last cell and produce that crash.

Please, who knows why it happens or have some ideas, help me with this problem.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use NSMutableArray instead of NSArray? That way, you can easily remove using 'removeLastObject' and then  reload CollectionView

Comment: I don't really know why I start using dictionary instead of array. But in real application there is no need to remove exactly last cell. It performs update data from server side and all may be changed

Comment: @Munahal, oops. I read your question wrong. I created CollectionViewController first and when in ViewController I need to set new data and I saw NSArray, I don't think of modifying CollectionViewController to fit new need, I just worked with what I already have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find out where is problem. I use lazy loading for dictionary with attributes and after layout was invalidated new attributes was added to dictionary. And earlier elements was here too. Now dictionary removed in - prepareLayout and all works good.

Thank you, Tristan Burnside. You lead me to right way.

Answer (score 2):

You should override 
[`- finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath:) 
and remove the attributes for the removed item from the layoutAttributes dictionary.

The assertion occurs because the collectionView asks for the layout attributes of the item after the last item and expects to get a nil response from the layout but because the attributes are still in your dictionary they are returned instead.

Comment: I'm using [collectionView reloadData]. Maybe because of that   - finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath: method did not calls.

Comment: now I understand that problem in layoutAttributes dictionary not updated for new elements array. But where I can update it if I use reloadData instead of removing cells one by one

Comment: you can do that in 
- finalizeCollectionViewUpdates

Comment: turns out that problem was in prepareLayout. I did not clear dictionary